# LyX displays Cyrillic characters when entering accented Latin characters

Tags: lyx, macos

working with macOS Monterey 12.7.2 (System Language is English and keyboard is US PC International), LyX 2.3.7 and MacTeX-2023, I encounter the strangest problem.  I'm using LyX out of the box after installing MacTex and running "reconfigure" and restarting LyX.

When I input in the LyX document edit view, say, an e accent aigue "é", I get the Cyrillic small letter of the short I: "й", and for the e accent grave "è" a Cyrillic small letter I: "и".

But in de code view pane I do see an "é" and an "è" and rendering the document to PDF does display the "é" and "è" !

I tried to force some encodings using

```latex
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

In the document preamble, but to no avail.

Why is the encoding (is it the encoding?) of the LyX document edit pane wrong, can I correct that? I've searched all configuration and settings of LyX I could find but I couldn't find any weird or out of place looking setting. To be fair, I updated everything because the same problem occurred with the previous version of LyX.

Answer (score 0):

I have no problems here: macOS 12.7.3, LyX 2.3.7, MacTeX 2023. You might do better to ask this question on the lyx-users mailing list.